# Make IntelliJ autoformatting of @deprecated work with Checkstyle

Tags: intellij-idea, javadoc, checkstyle, formatter

I have enabled *JavadocTagContinuationIndentation* in Checkstyle and now I'd like to make IntelliJ Idea's auto formatter format my Javadocs accordingly.

Everything works fine, except for multiline comments for *@deprecated* - apparently Idea's formatter doesn't treat this as a parameter. Is there a way to make it work?

Thanks,

Comment: `@deprecated` isn't a parameter, it's its own Javadoc tag.  I'm observing what you're seeing though...maybe IntelliJ doesn't have a way to format that and preserve whitespace?

Comment: Exactly - the best solution in my case would be to make IntelliJ treat Javadoc tags like parameters (like Checkstyle) but apparently there is no such setting (or at least I couldn't find it).